# When using Web Deploy for a .net core MVC web application, how to keep specific files at the destination?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, webdeploy

In Visual Studio, in the deployment settings of an asp.net core web application, I can tick an option to delete non-matching files at the destination.

Is there a way to keep a specific folder from being deleted during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

The web deploy will not delete your files in the destination, only if you check the option, if you do not want them to be removed, do not check the option.
But backup the files you want to keep on the server, backup is never too much!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I would like is to delete all files on destination, excepted one directory. Deleting files on destination is useful to clear old files from a previous deployment, that do not exist anymore in a new version. But keeping one directory from being deleted is useful as well, to store dynamic content, such as files uploaded by users of the web site.

Comment: Make the BackUp of the folder you want to save, run Web Deploy, with the option to delete files marked, and after finishing Web Deploy, return the folder you saved to the correct path, where it was previously.